# Magento 2: How to define Scope For Router.php

Tags: magento2, module, custom, routing

I have created Custom Module. As it requires some front-end routing, have to create `Router.php`

Whenever I'm accessing Magento eCommece Frontend other pages, say Category/Product Page. It will call my custom module's `Router.php`

So how can I limit that this `Router.php`, so it will be called only when I access my Custom Module (`App\Code\Custom\Module`)

In Addition, Due to this `Router.php`, my other custom module pages are not working, which is already working fine before.

I'm using this module as a reference for creating my custom module. https://github.com/tzyganu/Magento2SampleModule/tree/master/Controller

Due to this, my module's other pages are not working. Help needed Urgently.

**[UPDATE]**

Have issue with **app\code\Alphanova\ETrade\etc\frontend\routes.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
      <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/App/etc/routes.xsd">
      <router id="standard">
          <route id="mymodule" frontName="mymodule">
              <module name="Custom_Module" />
           </route>
      </router>
</config>
```

So other pages are working fine now. But now detail page is not working.

http://localhost/magento2/mymodule => Working

http://localhost/magento2/mymodule/test.html => Not Working.

Previous it's working when i have `<route id="custom_module" frontName="custom_module">` in `routes.xml`

**app\code\Custom\Module\etc\frontend\di.xml**

```
  <?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Framework\App\RouterList">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="routerList" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="Custom_Module" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="class" xsi:type="string">Custom\Module\Controller\Router</item>
                    <item name="disable" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="string">22</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </type>
    <virtualType name="CustomModuleRoutingEntityPosts" type="Custom\Module\Model\Routing\Entity">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="prefixConfigPath" xsi:type="const">Custom\Module\Model\Posts\Url::URL_PREFIX_CONFIG_PATH</argument>
            <argument name="suffixConfigPath" xsi:type="const">Custom\Module\Model\Posts\Url::URL_SUFFIX_CONFIG_PATH</argument>
            <argument name="factory" xsi:type="object">Custom\Module\Model\PostsFactory</argument>
            <argument name="controller" xsi:type="string">posts</argument>
        </arguments>
    </virtualType>
    <type name="Custom\Module\Controller\Router">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="routingEntities" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="posts" xsi:type="object">CustomModuleRoutingEntityPosts</item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </type>
</config>
```

**app\code\Custom\Module\Controller\Posts\View.php**

```
  public function execute() {
    echo "1111<pre>";
    exit;
  }
```

It's not going to controller & gives 404 page error.

**[Solved]**

It's issue with `$request->setModuleName('mymodule');` in Router.php, previously it's `$request->setModuleName('custom_module');`

Still question is why Product/Catalog routes go to my custom `Router.php`? How can i set that `Router.php` file only called for some Module & Controller otherwise not. Because we have configuration in `di.xml` so that's why it's calling

Answer (score 1):

You only need a custom `router.php` file if you plan to use custom urls. I mean something else than `module/controller/action`.
If you don't need urls like `mymodule/test.html` then you don't need that `router.php` file and you don't need this in `etc/frontend/di.xml`

```
<type name="Magento\Framework\App\RouterList">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="routerList" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="sample_news" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="class" xsi:type="string">Namespace\Module\Controller\Router</item>
                <item name="disable" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="string">10</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </arguments>
</type>
```

If you want url's like `mymodule/test.html` you need that router file.
And it is normal to have it called when you view the product pages.
Magento accepts a set of router classes. The method `match` is called from each of these classes until a route is matched to something.

Comment: Expecting answer from you @Marius.  `app\code\Custom\Module\Controller\Router.php` @ End of file when i do  `$this->dispatched = true; echo 1;exit;`. It works fine. But when i remove `exit` & @ last line `return $this->actionFactory->create(Forward::class);` it goes to 404 page.  What exactly i need to do?.  I have installed ur module it works fine. Issue is with my custom module which results 404 page.

Comment: Maybe the current url you are on is not matched to anything and you get a 404 page as you should.

Comment: I have added more info in question. Page Identifier / URL Key exists in database. Will get value from DB using `checkUrlKey` function.