# Magento 2: Submitted Form not calling Controller

Tags: magento2, module, controllers, custom, forms

To continue with the question below

[Magento 2: How to define Scope For Router.php](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/136401/magento-2-how-to-define-scope-for-router-php)

**app\code\Custom\Module\view\frontend\templates\posts\view.phtml**

```
<form class="form post reply"
      action="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getSaveUrl(); ?>"
      id="post_reply_form"
      name="postReplyForm"
      method="post"
      data-hasrequired="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('* Required Fields') ?>"
      data-mage-init='{"validation":{}}' 
    >
    <fieldset class="fieldset required">
        <?php echo $block->getBlockHtml('formkey') ?>
        <div class="field post_reply_description required">
            <label class="label" for="post_reply_description"><span><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Message') ?></span></label>
            <div class="control">
                <textarea name="post_reply_description" id="post_reply_description" title="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Description') ?>" class="input-text" cols="5" rows="3" data-validate="{required:true}"></textarea>
            </div>
        </div>
    </fieldset>
    <div class="actions-toolbar">
        <div class="primary">
            <button type="submit" title="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Submit') ?>" class="action submit primary">
                <span><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Submit') ?></span>
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

**app\code\Custom\Module\Block\Posts\ViewPosts.php**

```
namespace Custom\Module\Block\Posts;

use Magento\Framework\Registry;
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template;
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context;
use Magento\Framework\App\Filesystem\DirectoryList;
use Magento\Framework\Data\Collection;
use Magento\Framework\Filesystem;
use Magento\Framework\Image\AdapterFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Message\ManagerInterface;
use Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface;

class ViewPosts extends Template {

    /**
     * @var Registry
     */
    protected $coreRegistry;

    /**
     * @var ModuleURL
     */
    protected $ModuleURL;

    /**
     * @var _filesystem
     */
    protected $_filesystem;

    /**
     * @var _imageFactory
     */
    protected $_imageFactory;


    /**
     * @param Context $context
     * @param Registry $registry
     * @param array $data
     */
    public function __construct(
    Context $context, Registry $registry, Filesystem $filesystem, AdapterFactory $imageFactory, ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig, array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->coreRegistry = $registry;
        $this->_filesystem = $filesystem;
        $this->_imageFactory = $imageFactory;
        $this->scopeConfig = $scopeConfig;


        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }

    protected function _prepareLayout() {
        parent::_prepareLayout();
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Return the Url for saving.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getSaveUrl() {
        return $this->_urlBuilder->getUrl('mymodule/posts/postReplyForm');
    }
}
```

**app\code\Custom\Module\Controller\Posts\PostReplyForm.php**

```
namespace Custom\Module\Controller\Posts;

use Magento\Framework\App\Request\DataPersistorInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager;
use Magento\Framework\App\Filesystem\DirectoryList;

class PostReplyForm  {

    /**
     * @var DataPersistorInterface
     */
    private $dataPersistor;

    /**
     * Post user post
     *
     * @return void
     * @throws \Exception
     */
    public function execute() {
        $post = $this->getRequest()->getPostValue();

        echo "<pre>";
        print_r($_REQUEST);
        exit;
   }
}
```

What's reason why it's not going in controller file?

**[UPDATE]**

https://github.com/tzyganu/Magento2SampleModule/blob/master/Controller/Router.php

It's going to line number **151** & returing 404 page.

I would like to define scope (as my previous question) that when there is only detail page with .html extension then only it will call `Router.php` file otherwise it works as it is.

Trying to do patch over here

**app\code\Custom\Module\Controller\Router.php**

Which causes another error for redirection

```
if ($postsURLSuffix) {
    $suffix = substr($urlKey, -strlen($postsURLSuffix) - 1);
    if ($suffix != '.' . $postsURLSuffix) {
        // START FOR POST MESSAGE FORM REDIRECT
        if (strpos($request->getServer('REQUEST_URI'), 'postReplyForm') !== false) {
             $redirectURL = "http://localhost".$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
             $resultRedirect = $this->resultFactory->create(ResultFactory::TYPE_REDIRECT);
             $resultRedirect->setPath($redirectURL);
             return $resultRedirect;
        }
        // END FOR POST MESSAGE FORM REDIRECT
        return false;
    }
    $urlKey = substr($urlKey, 0, -strlen($postsURLSuffix) - 1);
}
```

Which gives fatal error

> Fatal error: Call to undefined method
>   Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\Redirect\Interceptor::execute() in
>   D:\wamp\www\magento2\vendor\magento\framework\App\FrontController.php
>   on line 57

Comment: Could you post the code in your `routes.xml` file please ?

Comment: try module/posts/postReplyFor with module/posts/postreplyfor

Comment: @RaphaelatDigitalPianism already mentioned `routes.xml` in previous question link

Comment: Sorry it's typo mistake in question i have updated question.

Answer (score 0):

You have to keep below code

```
public function getSaveUrl() {
    return $this->_urlBuilder->getUrl('mymodule/posts/postreplyform');
}
```

Comment: Sorry it's typo mistake in question i have updated question.

Comment: plz show your block file to more debug

Comment: Updated in question

Comment: I think there is an issue with Router.php  @Rakesh as i'm referring to that module for my development.