# Magento 2: How to use redirect in Router.php file [SOLVED]

Tags: magento2, module, custom, redirect, routing

As following  [Magento 2: How to define Scope For Router.php](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/136401/magento-2-how-to-define-scope-for-router-php) we already have

```
if ($condition->getRedirectUrl()) {
    $this->response->setRedirect($condition->getRedirectUrl());
    $request->setDispatched(true);
    return $this->actionFactory->create(Redirect::class);
}
```

But I have some condition due to that redirect other ways.

```
$resultRedirect = $this->resultFactory->create(ResultFactory::TYPE_REDIRECT);
$redirectURL = $request->getServer('REQUEST_SCHEME')."://".$request->getServer('SERVER_NAME').$request->getServer('REQUEST_URI');
$resultRedirect->setUrl($redirectURL);
```

Above is giving BLANK page.

```
$this->_redirect($redirectURL);
```

Above one is giving

> Call to undefined method Custom\Module\Controller\Router::_redirect()
>   in D:\wamp\www\magento2\app\code\Custom\Module\Controller\Router.php
>   on line 116

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally got the answer.

Thanks to https://github.com/zoransalamun/magento2-custom-router/blob/master/Controller/Router.php

Below is the code for `Router.php`

```
// START REDIRECT
        if (strpos($request->getServer('REQUEST_URI'), 'myList') !== false) {
                $request->setModuleName('myModule')->setControllerName('mylist')->setActionName('index');
                return $this->actionFactory->create(
                                'Magento\Framework\App\Action\Forward', ['request' => $request]
                );
            }
// STOP REDIRECT
```